# Mongoose MissingSchemaError on a .populate even though the schema is included

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose-schema

I have dug all I can and every "solution" I find is either a mistyped schema name or a missing / misordered require, which I'm quite certain is not what I'm running into.

I am using Typescript 2.6.2, Node 8.9.4, and Mongoose 5.0.2. I have two models. One is for Accounts and one for Organizations. When I run a findOne with a populate against the Accounts model, I get: 'MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Organization".'

/src/models/Organization.model.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export type OrganizationModel = mongoose.Document & {
   name: string,
   suborganizations: [OrganizationModel]
};

const OrganizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type String, required: true},
    suborganizations: [
        {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'}
    ]
});

const Organization = mongoose.model<OrganizationModel>('Organization', OrganizationSchema);
export default Organization;
```

/src/models/Account.model.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { default as Organization, OrganizationModel } from './Organization.model';

export type AccountModel = mongoose.Document & {
    username: string,
    organization: OrganizationModel
};

const Account = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    organization: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'}
});

const Account = mongoose.model<AccountModel>('Account', AccountSchema);
export default Account;
```

/src/controller/account.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
// I've tried without and with the following import
import { default as Organization, OrganizationModel } from '../models/Organization.model';
import { default as Account, AccountModel } from '../models/Account.model';

const AccountManager = {
    getAccount: async ({ username }) => {
        // Here is the troubled line
        const account = await Account.findOne({ username }).populate('organization organization.suborganizations');
        return account;
    }
};

export default AccountManager
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i guess this happened because your unused import was removed by compiler.

Try `import './Organization.model';`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that in a little bit. In the meantime, my workaround was to change the final `export default` in the models only to `export =`. Everything built fine with no errors, tests passed and all behaved as expected.